# Without using L'Hospital's rule and series expansion solve $e\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{n\ln(1+1/n)-1}-1}{n\ln(1+1/n)-1}n(n\ln(1+1/n)-1)$

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

This is my problem:

> Solve only with the basic rules of natural logarithm and the definition for $e$.
>
> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n(1+\frac{1}{n})^n - ne)$

And I got till here:

> $e\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-1}-1}{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-1}n(n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-1)$.

Both of these equations are equivalent with the limit $\frac{-e}{2}$. But I don't know how to transform to the next step. The first fraction should short itself giving me $1$ and the second multiplicand should give us $\frac{-1}{2}$ with the $e$ in front of the limit giving us the correct answer.

The definition for $e$ is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$.

But I think in this last step we should make a substitute $n = \frac{1}{x}$ and use the other definition $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e$

Comment: Hint: $n\ln (1+1/n)=\ln((1+1/n)^n)$

Comment: @vitamind Yes I know about that, but don't know how to make the connection I always get somewhere a $0$.

Comment: Oh my mistake, sorry.

Comment: This video by BlackPenRedPen provides a full solution to this problem : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPHHv1UcrMA&t=602s

Comment: @Algebrology Thank you so much !

Comment: @Algebrology But still this used differentiation.

Comment: @EdmondDantes Your title says: "Without using L'Hospital's rule".

Comment: @vitamind I jumped to the conclusion too fast.

Comment: @EdmondDantes But without L'Hospital's rule, I don't think so this is possible

Comment: Substituting $n=\frac1m$ transforms the limit to$$\lim_{m\to0}\frac{(1+m)^{\frac1m}-e}m$$which resembles the derivative of $f(m)=(1+m)^{\frac1m}$ at $m=0$. The derivative itself doesn't exist at this point, but $\lim\limits_{m\to0}f'(m)$ appears to have the same value of $-\frac e2$...

Comment: @EdmondDantes You can probably prove this by finding good bounds on $\log$ and $\exp$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write found inequalities here
$$\frac{1}{2n^2}- \frac{1}{n^3}\leqslant \frac{1}{n}-\ln\left(1+  \frac{1}{n}\right)\leqslant \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

**p.s.** I obtained expression identical to OP in [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172203/what-is-the-limit-of-lim-limits-n-to-infty-bigln-bigl1-frac1n-bigr/4172210#4172210), but  keep answer deleted, as hadn't inequalities in that time. We can prove them by examining the corresponding functions, but maybe someone will be able to see an elementary proof.